# 'Galleria' In WordPress- $ is not a function

Tags: wordpress, galleria

Trying to get Galleria script working in WordPress? I am have enqueued the script with this code, and it appears to be loading ok:

```
function add_scripts(){
// Load Galleria

wp_register_script('galleria',get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/galleria/galleria-1.2.2.min.js',array('jquery'),false);
wp_enqueue_script('galleria');
}
add_action('init','add_scripts');
```

In the post body I have the following, but all I get is the list of images:

```
<div id="gallery"><img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3316/3532175582_91f984df47.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3316/3532175582_91f984df47.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3316/3532175582_91f984df47.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
            $("#gallery").galleria({
                width: 500,
                height: 500
            });</script>
```

The error I receive is this: $ is not a function ... so the galleria script isn't firing right, or in the right order..

I have asked the question in the [Galleria forum](http://getsatisfaction.com/galleria/topics/galleria_in_wordpress_is_not_a_function) as well.

Thanks

This is the basic setup for Galleria, taken right from the documentation, which works fine as standalone html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="galleria/galleria-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="gallery">
            <img src="photo1.jpg">
            <img src="photo2.jpg">
            <img src="photo3.jpg">
        </div>
        <script>
            Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
            $("#gallery").galleria({
                width: 500,
                height: 500
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this a client-sided or server-sided error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing `$("#gallery")` with `jQuery("#gallery")`

According to this [post](http://elementdesignllc.com/2009/08/wordpress-jquery-is-not-a-function/), Wordpress reserves $ for [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/).

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, sometimes with wordpress you gotta do like this:

```
var $ = jQuery;
```

Or do what @zxt suggested.  That should work too.  The version of jQuery they use doesn't declare `$` variable to avoid conflicts if you are using other libraries that may use `$`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the jquery library in your page -- jquery is what defines "$".

Something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="someplace/on/your/server/jquery.js"/>
```

Comment: hi. the following is loading in the header, before the galleria script: <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js'></script>